# Mongo db not updating user

Tags: mongodb, react-native

I'm using the remote Mongo DB atlas and I'm trying to check if a user already uploaded a document and if not create a new one for them. Otherwise, just update their current entry but the record is not getting updated.

```
router.post('/updateUser/loe', requireAuth,  (req,res) => {
    if (!req.user) {
        errors.user = 'No user dound'
        res.status(404).json({errors})
        return     
    }

    const userId = req.user._id
    const letterOfEnrolment = req.body.letterOfEnrolment

    Document.findOne({userId}).then(doc => {
        if(!doc) {
            const file = new Document({userId, letterOfEnrolment})
            file.save()
                .then(file => res.json(file))
                // .catch((err) => {res.send(err)})
        } else {
            const updatedDoc =  Document.updateOne({userId}, { $set: {letterOfEnrolment}})
            updatedDoc.save()
            .then(file=> res.json(file))
        }
        


    })
    .catch((err) => res.send(err))

});
```

Comment: does the find work? did you check userId receives the data?

Comment: how did you define `Document`? and it seems that your `findOne` query parameter may not be working. have you tried querying it via the mongo shell?